# Get Input from command line parallel to executing http request

Tags: python, multithreading

In an application where I get input from a barcode scanner attached to a printer I would like to mark documents printed, based on an ID being scanned.

Since the network can be slow and the printer can be fast, I want to avoid the situation where the request has not finished and the program can not accept a new input when the next document is scanned.

I tried to solve this with threading but am stuck at this point. All I get is the error: `TypeError: updateOrder() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ids'`

Here is the full code:

```
import requests
from requests.models import HTTPBasicAuth
import threading

# Empty Array to buffer the incoming billbeeIds 

ids = [] 

# Get the order-id from the scanner

def getInput():
    while True: 
        newId = str(input("BillBeeId eingeben"))
        ids.append(newId)

# Mark order-id as printed

def updateOrder(ids):
    while len(ids) > 0:
        billbeeId = ids.pop(0)
        response = requests.post(
            'https://app.billbee.io/api/v1/orders/{0}/tags'.format(billbeeId),
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xxx', 'xxx'),
            headers={'X-Billbee-Api-Key': 'xxx'},
            json={
                "Tags": [
                    "Lieferschein-Gedruckt"
                ]
            }
        )
        print(response)   

t1 = threading.Thread(target=getInput)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=updateOrder, args=ids)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: You get the error because `args` is supposed to be a list or tuple of arguments and yours is empty in the beginning. You can get rid of this error by calling `t2 = threading.Thread(target=updateOrder, args=[ids])` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is using a `queue` :

```py
import threading
import queue
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

job_file = Path("job_done.txt")

q = queue.Queue()

def updateOrder():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        sleep(1)
        with open(job_file, 'a') as file_out:
            file_out.write(f"worked on {item}\n")
        q.task_done()


threading.Thread(target=updateOrder, daemon=True).start()

while True:
    try:
        # add job to the queue
        q.put(input("add item : "))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

q.join()
print('\nAll work completed')
```

I simulated a long task with a `sleep` and job executed get written to a file instead of being send through a request, but the reasoning should be the same.
works on python 3.9.2

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that!

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick! And it's not creating a 100% CPU load which my code did after fixing the syntax error 